# insert or update using if exists using merge oracle sql logic

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

i am fetching the data from transaction system back end oracle db and which is my source and target is also a same table one to one

i need to write a merge statement for checking insert or update based on new values

**Source Transaction table**

```
create table product 
(
product_id pk VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
product_nm VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
product_cd VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
product_dec VARCHAR2(500 CHAR),
insert_ts date,
update_ts date,
version NUMBER(38,0),
product_interval_strt NUMBER(38,0),- these are some numeric values
product_interval_end NUMBER(38,0) - these are some numeric values
)
```

since the etl (PDI) throwing error

Unable to get value 'Integer(38)' from database resultset, index 11 Numeric Overflow

so i have used the below so that PDI reads it as Bignumber 37

CAST (product_interval_strt AS number(37,0)) INTERVAL_START ,
CAST (product_interval_strt AS number(37,0)) product_interval_end

**Target Transaction table**

```
create table product_stg 
(
product_id pk VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
product_nm VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
product_cd VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
product_dec VARCHAR2(500 CHAR),
insert_ts date,
update_ts date,
version NUMBER(38,0),
product_interval_strt NUMBER(38,0),- these are some numeric values
product_interval_end NUMBER(38,0) - these are some numeric values
)
```

so i have used the below so that PDI reads it as Bignumber 37

```
CAST (product_interval_strt AS number(37,0)) INTERVAL_START ,
CAST (product_interval_strt AS number(37,0)) product_interval_end
```

so i need to prepare a merge sql statement to check if product_id exists do update doesn't exist do insert ,but i was not sure i only have to use the below

i need to prepare a simple merge statement if value exists update or insert

correct me if the below skeleton/structure is correct

```
merge into MY_TABLE tgt
using (select [expressions]
         from dual ) src
   on (src.key_condition = tgt.key_condition)
when matched then 
     update tgt
        set tgt.column1 = src.column1 [,...]
when not matched then 
     insert into tgt
        ([list of columns])
     values
        (src.column1 [,...]);
```

Comment: `PDI` is pentho ?

Comment: @Digvijay - Yes

Comment: @Lalith Kumar what is incorrect / updated - from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
when matched then  
     update tgt --> Incorrect syntax
        set tgt.column1 = src.column1 [,...]
when not matched then 
     insert into tgt --> Incorrect syntax
```

Your syntax is incorrect for `MERGE` statement. The target table name is already mentioned in `MERGE INTO`syntax, no need to specify the table name in the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` clause again. Correct syntax for update and insert clause is:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET TGT.product_nm = SRC.product_nm
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (TGT.product_id, TGT.product_nm .....)
    VALUES (SRC.product_id, SRC.product_nm .....);
```

Comment: @Lalith - Excellent for correcting my misunderstanding

Comment: @rakesh You're welcome, please mark it as answered.

Comment: @Lalith - why the ID column is not there in the update condition ?

Comment: @Lalith - i missed a point here both are diff servers , how to handle in this case ?

Comment: @rakesh You mean you have the source and destination tables in two different databases? Then you need to create a database link between them.

Comment: @rakesh You cannot have ID in update as it is the key on which you have the JOIN condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MERGE INTO product TGT
   USING (SELECT product_id
,product_nm
,product_cd
,product_dec
,insert_ts
,update_ts
,version
,CAST (product_interval_strt AS number(37,0)) INTERVAL_START 
,CAST (product_interval_strt AS number(37,0)) product_interval_end
FROM product_stg 
) SRC
   ON (SRC.product_id = TGT.product_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TGT.product_nm=SRC.product_nm ......)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (TGT.product_id, TGT.product_nm .....)
     VALUES (SRC.product_id, SRC.product_nm .....);
```

Comment: @Digvijjay i am trying , but can you see a sample structure if that is wrong ?

Comment: you are right thanks for the quick suggestion on the code

Comment: @Digvijjay - Why the ID column is not considered in the matched condition ?

Comment: You are matching based on `ID`  right. Its already present in table.